# VBA Copy data from a file and Paste it at the end of another file

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I have this macro file ("graphPrint.xls") that reads data from a file by copy-and-pasting into the macro file, which produces a graph using the data pasted.
Now, I need to modify this macro so that it can read data from 4 files, and combine all data together in the macro file, and produces one graph with all the data.

What I am trying to do, is

1. open the file to read data from,
2. copy the data in the file,
3. paste it into the macro file,
4. close the file. And I want to repeat this process in a for loop.

The problem here is at (3), when I paste the data read into the macro file, I have to make sure it is pasted at the end of the data each time so it will not replace the previous data.

Assume that file name is `file0.csv` up to `file3.csv`.
I have this macro:

```
Dim readFile As String;
For i = 0 To 3
    readFile = "file" + CStr(i) + ".csv"  'get file name
    WorkbooksOpen Filename:= readFile     'open file
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Select   'select all data from the file
    lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row    'edited
    Selection.Copy             'copy all
    Windows("graphPrint.xls").Activate   'open macro file

    ActiveSheet.Paste                   'paste here in macro file        

    Application.CutCopyMode = False    'cancel the copy mode
    Windows(readFile).Activate   
    ActiveWindow.Close            'close this file
Next i
```

However, this macro replaces the old data with new one when pasted each time, and hence, the graph shown will only use the data from the file that was read last. The file column start from "A1" through "Z1", so I change the

```
 ActiveSheet.Paste
```

with

```
 Range(Range("A1:Z1" & lastRow), ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial
```

, hoping it will paste it at the end of the macro file each time and that this way I can reflect all data into the graph. However, this gives

> "Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed"

error.

Can someone please guide me to a solution? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have your `lastrow` defined somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I skipped that line in the code above. I edited it. Still I am getting the same error. I just realized that each time lastRow is getting 65536...

Comment: Ok. So, if you have last row of your data, why you are not using it in a simple way? ;) `Range("A" & lastrow)` gives you the last cell in column A. Check again what are you doing in `Range("A1:Z1" & lastRow)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, use the `Find` function to get the `LastRow` from columns "A:Z".

```
Dim readFile As String
Dim LastCell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

For i = 0 To 3
    readFile = "file" + CStr(i) + ".csv"  'get file name
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=readFile ' open file

   ' get last row in columns "A:Z" using the Find method
    Set LastCell = ActiveSheet.Range("A:Z").Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not LastCell Is Nothing Then
        LastRow = LastCell.Row ' get last Row with data
    End If

    ' Copy >> Paste in 1 line
    Range("A1:Z" & LastRow).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("graphPrint.xls").ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

    Application.CutCopyMode = False    'cancel the copy mode
    Windows(readFile).Activate
    ActiveWindow.Close            'close this file
Next i
```

Comment: @Wang Dang have you tried my answer and code ? any feedback ?